# React useState array not resetting

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a functional component in which I use useState. I try to start with an empty array and it works fine when the component is rendered for the first time. But the component is often re-rendered and the array does not reset.

To give a bit of context, I have a page displaying customers data. I have a select component to change the customer. The data should of course change when I select another one.

**My Component**

```
const DataContainer = (props) => {
    const anotherProp = props.selectedInstallation;
    const initValues = props.initValues; // tried to use an empty array as prop
    const [arrValues,setArrayValues] = useState(initValues); // tried useState([]) as well
    console.log(props); // data here are correct and for the right customer
    console.log(anotherProp); // data here are correct and for the right customer
    console.log(initValues); // []
    console.log(arrValues); // should be empty but contains array from previous customer

    useEffect(() => {
        // code omitted
        // I use anotherProp to retrieve some data to use setArrayValues
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("props");
            console.log(props);
        },10000);
    },[anotherProp]);

    return (
        <div>
            {(arrValues.length > 0 ? (
                arrValues.map((value,idx) => {
                    return (
                        <Chart value={value} />
                    )
                })) : ""
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

export default DataContainer;
```

**Update**
I added an interval that logs the props. I should have a result every 10s but I have one every 5s. Once it logs data from the previous user, once data from the selected user...

**Update 2**
For the `arrValues` I tried `useState(initValues)` where `initValues`
is an empty array and `useState([])`. It logs an array with the data from the previous customer and not an empty array.

I don't understand why my `arrValues` is not empty... The data in my props is correct so I know the switch from one customer to another works. The two methods I used to set `arrValues` as an empty array don't work.

Comment: Can you check the value of initBatteries as well? try a console.log(initBatteries) after console.log(props)

Comment: Seems the reference of prop `anotherProp` did not change so `useEffect` did not get triggered as it is the same reference.

Comment: State is not reinitialized on prop change. You should watch the prop with use effect and call set state from there. `useEffect(()=>{setArrayValues(props.initProp)}, [props.initProp]);` (where `initProp` is what ever property you are tracking)

Comment: @RaoVirinchi `initBatteries` was a error. It is `initValues`. I tried to force an empty array using props

Comment: @pavlovic265 `anotherProp` did change. It contains data about the customer and it does update when I select another one

Comment: One more thing that comes to mind is the way you are calling to fetch data from `useEffect`. Checkout article from [overreacted-complete-guide-to-useeffect](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) seems it is covering issue you have.
In short, you need to wrap code omitted and setArrayValues with IIFE
`useEffect(() => { (async () => { // code omitted &use setArrayValues })() },[anotherProp]);`

Comment: Can you change the useState to const [arrValues,setArrayValues]=useState([]) and confirm that the console.log(arrValues) doesn't log an empty array? If it is logging an empty array, please insert a log statement in the useEffect function and check if the useEffect is being called before your console log. If that is the case, the function in useEffect might be altering state.

Comment: @RaoVirinchi I did change it and I confirm it does not give an empty array. When I change the customer, the component is rendered multiple times. The first two times, `console.log(arrValues)` logs an array with data from previous user. Then I have a correct log twice.

Comment: Can you please share your output after inserting the console log that I requested in my previous comment?

Comment: @RaoVirinchi When the component is rendered, the current user is used. The `console.log(arrValues)` starts as an empty array and it gets filled when user data are retrieved: `['2715']`. When the second user is selected the `arrValues` starts with the data from the previous user `['2715']`. It is later updated `['1310','112']` but I need it to be empty first...